# JIRA opensource licence

Tags: licensing, jira

I saw this on the licensing information section on the Jira website

```
JIRA is free for use by official non-profit organisations and charities (proof of     non-profit status is required). There are certain organisations whose purpose is to make the world a better place, and we believe in helping them achieve that.

Community licenses are designed for organisations which are:

    * non-profit,
    * non-government,
    * non-academic,
    * non-commercial,
    * non-political and
    * secular
```

What does the last bullet point actually mean? Does it mean that if you believe in God you cant have a free license for a bug tracking software product?

Comment: Separation of church and session-state?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. See [[here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846)] for details, and the [[help/on-topic]] for more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would imagine that you as an individual may believe in God(s), but the organisation itself should not be a religious organisation.

Comment: Yes but i wonder what is the reason behind not allowing lets say a church access to the free license given then a church organisation is not a commercial organisation.

Comment: I am speculating, but some may argue that with church way of funding, the church operates as a commercial foundation. Anyways, the product developers have a free will to have their own beliefs and opinions.

Comment: Atlassian has a right to give away their software to whomever they want, but Atlassian's is far from a neutral stance: a neutral stance would be to remove that clause. Under their license terms, an organization like Americans United or Freedom from Religion Foundation can obtain a license, and they (especially the latter) are far from neutral. And regarding Eugene's comment, AU and FFRF are far more well-funded than nearly all religious groups. This is clearly pure secularism: see jira's license statement where only secular organizations are the ones who "make the world a better place".

Comment: The license agreement certainly does not state that secular organisations are ones which make the world a better place IMO.

Comment: @EugeneKuleshov it doesn't convince me really... They specifically narrow it down to organizations that are "(...) non-commercial in nature, have no religious affiliation (...)", so being an explicitly non-commercial, but still religious organization (say, a Christian charity foundation) is a no-no just the same. Noone is questioning their right to give out free licenses to whoever they please - but then it's also our right to comment on that as we please.

Comment: @NotJarvis it does not state that, but it indirectly implies that religious organizations are not. I'm not judging whether it's true or not, but it certainly is a political belief in its own right.

Comment: So no licenses for the internationally known charity organization, "Salvation Army" which focuses on helping the homeless and hungry? Seems rather silly to me. I get people not being religious... I just don't get people being religiously anti-religion. "*We think you sow hatred and exclusion... So we're going to hate and exclude you!*" =P

Answer (score 5):

I actually asked Atlassian support the very same question a year ot two ago and they said that they don't do community licenses for churches etc. Seemed a bit restrictive to me.

Comment: More discussion about this at http://www.volokh.com/2010/01/14/interesting-software-licensing-agreement/